# User controls in PHP with parameters

Tags: php, user-controls

i am new to .php. I would like to know what are all the ways we can create User Controls (How we do it in asp.net). This found with include in php, but i need to pass parameters to it and use those parameters in that php include file.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960097/alternative-of-asp-nets-usercontrols-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to use a php framework for web development. Standalone php is too generic and unstructured to be effective in development.

To answer your question, if you decide to use a framework such as Symfony you will find it comes equipped to handle "User Controls" using "Partials", "Components", and "Widgets".

See http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer for more information.

--

If you decide not to use a framework, then your best bet would be to put the HTML code, in an include file (e.g. myControl.inc.php) and then include it manually in your main layout using:

Again, I'd strongly discourage anyone from developing a php application without a framework.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I did an experiment to mimic ASP.NET behaviour using PHP + JavaScript.

A vague example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
 "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict (jaFramework-Edition)//EN//"
 "http://www.joelalejandro.com/ja-xhtml/ja-xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:ja="http://www.joelalejandro.com/ja-xhtml/" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jaXHTML.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ja:MySQLServer
                    id="MySQL1"
                    ConfigFile="mysql1.conf">
    </ja:MySQLServer>
    <ja:Grid
             id="Grid1"
             UsingConnection="MySQL1"
             DataSource="urminute_com.mp_songs">

    </ja:Grid>
    <script>
        alert(window.Grid1.DataSource);
    </script>
</body>
```

I took XHTML 1.0 Strict's definition file and added the "ja:" tags. Then, using Javascript DOM and AJAX, I replaced the tags with the content that I was required to deliver.

I don't know exactly how *efficient* the solution is, yet is XHTML-compliant.

Just my two cents on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Can't this be achived using "get" parameters in the include call? Something like:

include 'control.php?param1=value1';